# actionscript 3 - how to get all properties from my Object?

Tags: actionscript-3

How to get all properties from my Object ?

My object is:

```
var myObj: Object = {
    stringOne: "One",
    stringTwo: "Two",
    intOne: 1,
    intTwo: 2
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get list of properties in an object in Actionscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372317/how-can-i-get-list-of-properties-in-an-object-in-actionscript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
for(var key:* in myObj) {
    trace (key + ':' + myObj[key]);
}
```